# Python Pandas optimization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I'm currently working on optimizing the following function :

```
def process_column(feature, X, y):
    df = pd.DataFrame({feature: X[feature], 'quality': y})
    df = df.sort_values(feature).reset_index(drop=True)
    thresholds = np.quantile(df[feature].dropna(), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
    indices = df[feature].searchsorted(thresholds, side='right')

    y_tuples = [(df.iloc[:i]['quality'].tolist(), df.iloc[i:]['quality'].tolist()) for i in indices]
    return y_tuples, thresholds
```

This function takes a feature column from a DataFrame `X`, along with a Series `y` containing class labels (0, 1). It creates a DataFrame combining these, sorts it, and then calculates quantiles and indices. The final output includes tuples of `y` values, split according to the calculated indices and associated thresholds.

Currently, I apply this function to each feature in my dataset individually. However, this approach is quite time-consuming, especially with larger datasets. I'm exploring ways to apply the logic of this function to all features in `X` simultaneously, rather than processing each feature one by one. Any suggestions or insights on how to efficiently handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried using parallelisation but I don't have the computer for it.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: What does it mean to apply it to all features simultaneously? You can only sort by one feature at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here the approach aims to be more efficient by using vectorized operations and JIT compilation, also I do use Dask, although you mentioned limitations with parallel processing Dask is designed to work efficiently even on single machines.

That being said, to get you familiar with refactorized code `X` - represents DataFrame of features, `y` - a series of labels.
with `df = pd.concat([X, y.rename('quality')], axis=1)` all `X`'s and `y`'s are combined in single DataFrame. After that, comes `quantiles = X.apply(lambda col: np.quantile(col.dropna(), np.linspace(0, 1, 20)))` which is basically calculating 20 quantiles for each feature, which is done by `np.quantile` and applied to each column (feature) of `X`. Inside loop, `df` is sorted and we reset its index, which is assigned to `sorted_df`.
-`y_tuples = compute_tuples_jit(sorted_array, thresholds)` - calls a JIT-compiled function (JIT - Just-In-Time compilation via the Numba library can significantly speed up computations, especially when it comes to loops). Function after `@jit` - is compiled at runtime, which is also enhancing execution speed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit

def process_columns_advanced(X, y):
    df = pd.concat([X, y.rename('quality')], axis=1)
    quantiles = X.apply(lambda col: np.quantile(col.dropna(), np.linspace(0, 1, 20)))

    result = {}
    for feature in X.columns:
        # Sort the DataFrame based on the current feature
        sorted_df = df.sort_values(feature).reset_index(drop=True)
        thresholds = quantiles[feature]
        sorted_array = sorted_df.values
        y_tuples = compute_tuples_jit(sorted_array, thresholds)
        result[feature] = (y_tuples, thresholds)

    return result

@jit(nopython=True)
def compute_tuples_jit(sorted_array, thresholds):
    result = []
    for threshold in thresholds:
        # Compute index
        index = np.searchsorted(sorted_array[:, 0], threshold, side='right')
        # Split array and create tuple
        tuple_y = (sorted_array[:index, -1].tolist(), sorted_array[index:, -1].tolist())
        result.append(tuple_y)
    return result

# Example on how to use
# X = pd.DataFrame(...) # Your features DataFrame
# y = pd.Series(...)    # Your labels Series
# result = process_columns_advanced(X, y)
```